# Prove the following set is a meagre set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\ell^2$ be the space of square-summable sequences of real numbers equipped with the metric 
$$d(x, y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-y_i)^2}$$,
where $x = (x_1, x_2, . . .)$, $y = (y_1, y_2, . . .)$. Determine whether set $Y$ is meagre, where $Y \subset \ell^2$ consists of those sequences that have only finitely many nonzero terms
each of which is a rational number.

Here is my attempt and a sketch proof:

$Y$ can be written as
$$
Y = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty X_i,
$$
where $X_i$ consists of all eventually $0$ sequences with the $i$-th term being the last non-zero rational term. Then $X_i$ can essentially be conisdered as equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}^i$. Since $\mathbb{Q}^i$ is meagre, then countable union of meagre sets is also meagre.

Is my idea correct? If it's correct, how can I finesse the proof? Especially, how do I argue that $X_i$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}^i$?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not valid. $\mathbb Q^{i}$ is meager in some other space and saying that $X_i$ is equivalent that is not a valid argument.

The closure of $X_i$ in $\ell^{2}$ consists of all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n=0$ for all $n >i$. This set is closed. Also, any proper subspace of a normed linear space has empty interior. Hence $X_i$ is a nowhere dense set for each $i$.

Comment: I'm not sure what proper subspace of normed linear space means.. We haven't covered anything like that in my class. Can you possibly dumb it down a bit? Thank you so much!

Comment: @davidolohowski The closure $Y_i$ of $X_i$ is a vector subspace. If it has an interior point then some ball $B(x_0,r)$ would be contained in it. But then $x_0$ belongs to $Y_i$ and now you can check that $B(0,r) \subseteq Y_i$. Now take any sequence not in  $Y_i$, say $(\frac 1 n)$. Call it $x$. Then $\frac 1 N x$ would have norm less t ha $r$ for large enough $N$. So  $\frac 1 N x \in Y_i$. Since $Y_i$ is a subspace this implies $x =N (\frac 1 N x) \in Y_i$. But we know that $x \notin Y_i$.

Comment: Ah.. I see, thank you very much!